# Convert model .pkcls to .h5 file

Tags: pickle, tensorflow2.0, hdf5, orange

I created and saved a NN model in a pickled model in Orange3 (model.pkcls). I'm looking to convert it in HDF5 file (model.h5) in order to use it with TensorFlow lite. How can I do that?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, only Tensorflow or keras model can be converted to tensorflow lite.
I think you have to retrain your model in those platform first.